# How to set label to Kubernetes node at creation time?

Tags: kubernetes

I am following up guide [1] to create multi-node K8S cluster which has 1 master and 2 nodes. Also, a label needs to set to each node respectively.

```
Node 1 - label name=orders 
Node 2 - label name=payment
```

I know that above could be achieved running kubectl command

```
kubectl get nodes
kubectl label nodes <node-name> <label-key>=<label-value>
```

But I would like to know how to set label when creating a node. Node creation guidance is in [2].

Appreciate your input.

[1] https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/getting-started.html

[2] https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/deploy-workers.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This answer is now incorrect (and has been for several versions of Kubernetes). Please see the correct answer by Radek 'Goblin' Pieczonka**

There are a few options available to you. The easiest IMHO would be to use a *systemd unit* to install and configure kubectl, then run the `kubectl label` command. Alternatively, you could just use `curl` to update the labels in the [node's](http://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1/definitions/#_v1_node) [metadata](http://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1/definitions/#_v1_objectmeta) directly.

That being said, while I don't know your exact use case, the way you are using the labels on the nodes seems to be an effort to bypass some of Kubernetes key features, like dynamic scheduling of components across nodes. I would suggest rather than work on labeling the nodes automatically that you try to address why you need to identify the nodes in the first place.

Comment: Yup. I agree with you. But my requirement is to create pods on nodes where it matches the label. Because there would be so many pods running in K8S cluster and it's easy for me to understand which pod runs on which node.

Comment: The whole intent of Kubernetes is that you don't need to know, nor care, about which pod runs where. Kubernetes is an abstraction specifically to remove the burden of knowing what is running where, and to allow for things to move to other nodes _when (not if)_ failures occur.

Answer (score 11):

In fact there is a trivial way to achieve that since 1.3 or something like that.

What is responsible for registering your node is the kubelet process launched on it, all you need to do is pass it a flag like this `--node-labels 'role=kubemaster'`. This is how I differentiate nodes between different autoscaling groups in my AWS k8s cluster.

Comment: seems like my `v1.7.3+coreos.0` cluster does not detect, that the CLI argument of kubelet has changed.`--node-labels mapStringString                              <Warning: Alpha feature> Labels to add when registering the node in the cluster.  Labels must be key=value pairs separated by ','.`

Comment: According to https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/51858 it only applies during the initial node registration.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't creation time but, the following is pretty easy (labels follow pattern of `key=value`):

```
k label node minikube gpu.nvidia.com/model=Quadro_RTX_4000 node.coreweave.cloud/cpu=intel-xeon-v2
node/minikube labeled
```